# JLayeredPane with JPanel and JLabel with Icon

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlayeredpane

I am trying to add to controls (`JPanel` and `JLabel`) on `JFrame` using a `JLayeredPane`.

Label is having the background image with the help of `ImageIcon` and panel is having button controls on it. It's showing the jlabel with background image

But panel controls are not displaying. I am using the following code.

```
   try
  {
  JLayeredPane layers= new JLayeredPane();
  ImageIcon img1= ImageIcon("path upto image");
  JLabel l1= new JLabel("");
  l1.setIcon(img1);


  JPanel panel1   = new JPanel();

   layers.add(l1);
  layers.add(panel1);

  add(layers);
 }
catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
```

How to display the panel controls?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: On a JLayeredPane the items are also ordered with a z-position on layers. I would advise to use layers.add(child, layer) instead of the simple add method. See [The Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html) for information about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, components don't have position or size, meaning if you add them to a container that has no layout manager (as is the case with `JLayeredPane`), they will not appear.

Because `JLayeredPane` has no layout manager, you must take over the responsibility of provide position and size information to your components.

Try using `setSize`, `setLocation` and/or `setBounds`.

Take a look at the examples from [How to use layered panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) for more details.

Comment: *"Try using.."* ..a layout manager!  Just because it does not have one by default, does not mean you can't set one.

Comment: @AndrewThompson LOL...true, context would be nice

Comment: @AndrewThompson To my (small) mind, `JLayeredPane` is great for dragging stuff around on, but that's just me...

Comment: its working now when i changed the order to add now i added first the  jpanel and then jlabel with background image